# How to update Subversion the nicest way?

Tags: linux, svn, update

I would like to update my Subversion server to a new version and don't find any documentation on this, so I'm asking this.

How can I update Subversion (1.4.6 to 1.6.3) on Linux the easiest way?

What can be harmed there? Keyword: APR etc.

The distro is RHEL and has no access to the internet.

Any help or warnings are appreciated.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you install the lastest version of subversion, then run "svnadmin upgrade" (which often does nothing at all - repository format upgrades are rare).

You should, of course, take a backup first.

The upgrade notes are part of the [release](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html#repos-upgrades) [notes](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#repos-upgrades).

Answer (score 1):

Not my answer, but I did come across this the other day:

> And for SVN database upgrade, you better "svnadmin dump" your repository(es)
>   using current server installation, then prepare an upgrade, make test
>   repository, check that it working fine, then restore your actual repos.

sb

Answer (score 0):

WAndisco Subversion Binaries have autoupdate capability:

Free Download: http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/os/downloads

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.